# SQL getting shifts outside of availability

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to put together an sql query to get employee shifts that are outside of their availability for a scheduling app. Availability entries will be contiguous and will never have availability entries that are back-to-back for the same employee, nor will there be availability entries that overlap for the same employee.

Basically, I need to get the shift rows where (`availabilities.start <= shifts.start AND availabilities.end >= shifts.end`) does NOT hold true. Phrased another way, I need to get the rows from the shifts table that are not fully contained by an availability entry.

It needs to account for these possibilities:

- Shifts that start before availability
- Shifts that end after availability
- Shifts that do not have any availability during the shift

I'm ok with using a stored procedure instead of a query if this would be more efficient.

Here's what the tables look like:

```
CREATE TABLE availabilities (`id` int primary key, `employee_id` int, `start` datetime, `end` datetime);
CREATE TABLE shifts (`id` int primary key, `employee_id` int, `start` datetime, `end` datetime);
```

Here is some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO availabilities
    (`employee_id`, `start`, `end`)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-01-01 08:00:00', '2015-01-01 09:00:00'),
    (1, '2015-01-02 08:00:00', '2015-01-02 10:00:00'),
    (2, '2015-01-03 08:00:00', '2015-01-03 14:00:00'),
    (2, '2015-01-04 08:00:00', '2015-01-04 18:00:00')
;

INSERT INTO shifts
    (`employee_id`, `start`, `end`)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-01-01 08:00:00', '2015-01-01 09:00:00'),
    (1, '2015-01-02 08:30:00', '2015-01-02 10:00:00'),
    (1, '2015-01-02 10:30:00', '2015-01-02 12:00:00'),
    (2, '2015-01-03 08:00:00', '2015-01-03 09:00:00'),
    (2, '2015-01-03 09:00:00', '2015-01-03 14:30:00'),
    (2, '2015-01-04 09:30:00', '2015-01-04 17:30:00'),
    (2, '2015-01-05 08:00:00', '2015-01-05 10:00:00')
;
```

I would expect the 3rd, 5th and 7th shifts to be output as they are outside of availability.

I've tried something like the following (as well as many others) however all of them either give false positives or leave out shifts.

```
SELECT s.*  FROM `shifts` AS `s`
LEFT JOIN `availabilities` AS `a` ON `s`.`employee_id` = `a`.`employee_id`
WHERE (NOT(a.start <= s.start AND a.end >= s.end) OR a.id IS NULL);
```

Comment: What did you tried ? Put some sample data and expected output .

Comment: also put the table structure with some records and what would be your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
select *
from shifts as s
where not exists (
    select 1
    from availabilities as a
    where a.start <= s.start AND a.end >= s.end and a.employee_id = s.employee_id
)
```

Comment: This appears to do exactly what I needed. Thanks!